# Insert Element within specific tags

Tags: c#, xml, insert, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to insert an element at a specific point within my file, then save that file out. However, I can't seem to get it right. My XML layout is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
   <Items />
   <Users />
</Settings>
```

This is my current code:

```
            XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");

            var newPosition =  xdoc.Root.Elements("Users");
            //I've tried messing around with newPosition methods


            XElement newItem = new XElement("User",
                new XAttribute("Name", "Test Name"),
                new XAttribute("Age", "34"),

                ); 

            //how can I insert 'newItem' into the "Users" element tag in the XML file?

            xd.Save(new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml"));
```

I'd like to use Linq to XML to insert 'newItem' into the  tag. Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find the Users element, and append it:

```
// Note that it's singular - you only want to find one
XElement newPosition = xdoc.Root.Element("User");
XElement newItem = new XElement("User",
     new XAttribute("Name", "Test Name"),
     new XAttribute("Age", "34"));

// Add the new item to the collection of children
newPosition.Add(newItem);
```

Your use of `var` here was leading you astray - because the type of `newPosition` in your code was really `IEnumerable<XElement>`... you were finding *all* the `User` elements. (Okay, there would only have actually *been* one element, but that's irrelevant... it was still conceptually a sequence.)